# Properly convert png to npy numpy array (Image to Array)

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, image-processing

When I generate an image and then generate a numpy array from it, the original `.npy` file differs from the new one. I thought `new-array.npy` would be exactly the same as `original-array.npy` since they are coming from the same image.

For an example, I used this little image with 4*4 pixels:
[original-image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpSxj.png)

Here is a larger version (not the one I'm working with):
[image]

The last part of the code is the one that converts the `.png` to `.npy`. I think the problem is in here somewhere.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

filename = 'image-test'

img = Image.open( filename + '.png' )
data = np.array( img, dtype='uint8' )

np.save( filename + '.npy', data)

# visually testing our output
img_array = np.load(filename + '.npy')
plt.imshow(img_array)
```

My simple algorithm:

1. Generate random rgb array and save it as `.npy`
2. Save a `.png` file from that numpy array.
3. Load that `.png` file and save it back to `.npy`

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

from PIL import Image                                                                                


####create a matrix of random colors
filename = "original-array"

matrix=np.random.random((4,4,3))
nx,ny,nz=np.shape(matrix)
CXY=np.zeros([ny, nx])
for i in range(ny):
    for j in range(nx):
        CXY[i,j]=np.max(matrix[j,i,:])

#Save binary data
np.save(filename + '.npy', CXY)
print(filename + " was saved")

#Load npy
img_array = np.load(filename + '.npy')
plt.imshow(img_array)


####Save npy as png
filename = "original-image"

img_name = filename +".png"
matplotlib.image.imsave(img_name, img_array)
print(filename + " was saved")


#### Convert that png back to numpy array

img = Image.open( filename + '.png' )
data = np.array( img, dtype='uint8' )

#Convert the new npy file to png
filename = "new-array"

np.save( filename + '.npy', data)
print(filename + " was saved")


#Load npy
img_array = np.load(filename + '.npy')

filename = "new-image"
#Save as png
img_name = filename +".png"
matplotlib.image.imsave(img_name, img_array)
print(filename + " was saved")
```

Here is the result :
[image]

When I regenerate an image from `new-array.npy` I get exactly the same image as `original-image.png`:
[image]

Comment: Just so you know, the pixel data in PNG files is compressed. A tiny change in the data, but also a different compression algorithm, may change the file size. To compare the actual data, do so on the decompressed pixels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is that my idea is to be able to use that array back for a machine learning algorithm and for that it has to be the same after conversion. How could I do ?

Comment: I mean because of that tiny change I'm getting the error :  

IndexError: index 2323 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1400  

When I convert an 2400*1400 png to a numpy array and the try to use it.    
Which is not so strange since the files seems to have different bounds..

Comment: The PNG file format stores pixels as *integers*.  You can't save data from a floating point array (such as your `CXY` or `img_array`) to a PNG file and expect to read back the same values.

Comment: Also note that your original array (either `CXY` or `img_array`) are two-dimensional, with shape (4, 4).  When you use `matplotlib.image.imsave` to create a PNG file, it converts each floating point value in the array to an RGB pixel using a colormap.  To summarize my previous comment and this one: the PNG file does not contain the same data as the numpy array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations :-) .I would like to be able to create at least an array (.npy) that would work with my script.. original-array.npy work like charm and when I try to load the new-array.npy I'm getting : " ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() " It seems to go out of boundaries? How could I create an array that matches the requirements to be as close as possible to the original-array. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Your array `CXY` contains floating point numbers in the range 0..1. PNG files can only store integer numbers, and cannot therefore store your floating point values.

Answer (score 1):

The files are different because the arrays have different data types.

The first time you save the data is when you save the array CXY. This array has a type of `np.float64`, since that is the default data type returned by `np.zeros`.

The second array is created by loading the original image, not the saved npy file. This is where the inconsistencies are introduced, since the PNG data is of type `np.uint8` (and is cast again to `np.uint8` in the next line). This is a smaller data type, hence the smaller overall file size.